# Question regarding an upper sum

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have a piecewise function and need to calculate an upper sum with $5$ subintervals.

The function in question is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if }0\le x < 1 \\ 2 & \text{if } x=1 \\ 4-x & \text{if }1<x\le 2\end{cases}$$

The interval is $[0,2]$, so a length of $2$. That makes $5$ subintervals, each with a length of $2/5$. The subintervals are $[0,2/5],[2/5,4/5],[4/5,6/5],[6/5,8/5]$ and $[8/5,2]$. I have managed to find suprema and infima for all other intervals except $[4/5,6/5]$ since the function is discontinuous at $1$.

I'm pretty sure that the infimum would be $f(4/5)=4/5$, since $f$ is defined at this point. Defining the supremum is a bigger issue though. It can't be $f(1)=2$, since the function obtains values larger than this on the subinterval, but the same issue arises with $f(6/5)$... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you drawn the graph of the function $f$? It should be quite clear from the graph what the value should be, the rest is reasoning exactly why it is so. It should help to note that the supremum need not be obtained by the function.

Comment: @Manifoldski so the supremum would be 3, although that value is never obtained?

Comment: An extremum that is obtained is called a "maximum" or "minimum". The terms "supremum" and "infimum" were coined exactly because sometimes extrema are not obtained. Any value lower than $3$ cannot be the supremum, because the function takes on higher values. Any value higher than $3$ cannot be the supremum because $3$ is an upper bound on the values of $f$ which is below such numbers. Only $3$ has the property of being an upper bound, but not having any other upper bounds below it. That is the definition of the supremum.